# Menubar do Primefaces não entra em div

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Boa noite.

Minha menubar não está entrando na div em que está contida.

```
<header>
    <h:graphicImage library="img" name="logo.jpg" id="logo"/> 
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="messages"/>

        <p:menubar>
            <p:menuitem value="Pesquisa" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Software" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Materiais" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Contato" url="#"/>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</header>
```

O CSS de ambas é:

```
header {
    background-color: #333;
}

#logo {
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
    display: inline;
}

.ui-menubar,.ui-menu-child,.ui-menu {
    float:right;
    margin-right:15%;
    width: 26% !important;  
    background-color: #aaa; 
}

.ui-menuitem-link.ui-corner-all.ui-state-hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Com isto, estou obtendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero fazer é colocar este menu dentro do header, ao lado da logo.

Comment: Poderia incluir o **Markup** gerado pelos componentes?

Comment: O que seria o Markup? Sou novo em Primefaces.

Comment: Seria o html gerado para o cliente.

Comment: Eu acabei resolvendo este problema de outra forma. Fiz com HTML mesmo.

Entendi o que é o Markup agora. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.